# Highstock error Invalid date

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I use denwer (local web server). I have uploaded all the files from denwer to the server in the Internet. Databases are the same and all files too.
All work well. Dates and values ​​are displayed correctly.
This code work well on local web server and in the Internet server.

```
  $limit='LIMIT 10';
$query="SELECT `date`,`data_input_1` FROM `$board_input_name` ORDER BY `id` $limit";
```

I want to give Highstock last 10 values from my base.
I change my code.

```
    $limit='LIMIT 10';
$query="SELECT `date`,`data_input_1` FROM `$board_input_name` ORDER BY `id` DESC $limit";
```

And this code work well on local web server and incorrect in the Internet server. In the Internet server, Highstock wrote "Invalid date" on x axe. On y axe values is correct.
If i remove DESC or replace it with ASC all work well on local web server and in the Internet server.

I called the script directly, to see what json data was given to Highstock. Data is correct.
And this is understandable - the scripts are identical and the base too.
What is the problem in DESC? And why Highstock wrote "Invalid date" on x axe when json data is correct and javascript is "client language"?

Comment: Does a bigger id have a bigger date?

Comment: Yes. The bigger id have a bigger date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case a bigger ID also seems to mean a bigger date, and this is most likely why you are experiencing problems. The ID itself doesn't matter, but the connection between ID and date caused it to "accidentally" work when sorted ascending, and definitely not work when sorting descending.

When using Highstock, which uses a `datetime` x-axis, it is a requirement that the x-axis is sorted in ascending order. This is because Highstock won't do the sorting for you (for performance reasons), and drawing and connecting points that are not sorted doesn't work. If the error is spotted by Highstock it usually generates a  ["Highcharts error 15"](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/15) in your console, which states that:

> **Highcharts expects data to be sorted**
>
> This happens when you are trying to create a line series or a stock chart where the data is not sorted in ascending X order. For performance reasons, Highcharts does not sort the data, instead it is required that the implementer pre-sorts the data.